# Como fazer para que, se existir o registro, ele faça update, se não faça um insert do mesmo

Tags: php, sql-update, sql-insert

Sou iniciante no fórum e em php e estou com uma dúvida. Tenho uma tabela com id auto_incremento e nome é chave primária. Tem como eu fazer IF e ELSE utilizando UPDATE e INSERT. Onde, se existir nome apenas fazer update, caso contrário fazer insert ?

```
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";    
                    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
                                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

                    $result_dados_pessoais = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, cpf) VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf')";
                    $resultado_dados_pessoais= mysqli_query($conn, $result_dados_pessoais);
                    //ID do usuario inserido
                    }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Por PHP**

```
    <?php

           if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
                    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
                    $sql1 = ("SELECT * FROM usuarios Where nome='$nome'");
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $result_dados_pessoais = ("UPDATE usuarios SET cpf='".$cpf."' Where nome='".$nome."'"); 
                }else{
                    $result_dados_pessoais = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, cpf) VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf')";
                    //ID do usuario inserido
                }
                $resultado_dados_pessoais= mysqli_query($conn, $result_dados_pessoais);
           }
    ?>
```

**outra forma com if else**

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '".$nome."'")) {
    $result_dados_pessoais = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE usuarios Set cpf = '".$cpf."' WHERE nome = '".$nome."'");
} else {
    $result_dados_pessoais = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, cpf) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$cpf."')");
}
```

Comment: a primeira forma alterou todos os registros do banco de dados kkkk

Comment: @Victor vc tinha que ter completado o update com clausula where, eu não imaginava que vc não sabia disso. Editei a resposta

Comment: eu tinha colocado duas clausulas where KKK foi por isso, mas depois consertei, na verdade até posso colocar duas clausulas né mas em uma tabela que contenha mais campos

Comment: Isso tá errado. Outra coisa, se vc verifica se o nome existe e ele existir porque fazer update no nome, não seria só no cpf?

Comment: Sim, eu fiz isso é que eu criei isso só para exemplificar e ficar curto, porém eu tenho campos como : Descricao do produto, Codigo do Produto, Unidade de Medida que é vendido, Codigo de Referencia... e então queria saber se eu conseguiria usar duas clausulas where, creio que deve dar

Comment: @Victor ... WHERE nome='$nome' AND `cpf`='$cpf'

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa do PHP, ao menos tem como ignorar ele dependo do caso.

---

No MySQL você tem um recurso similar, que pode ser feito nativamente feito com o [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html), segundo o manual.

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

*O REPLACE funciona exatamente com o o INSERT, exceto se uma linha antiga na tabela tiver o mesmo valor da nova linha para os indexes de PRIMARY KEY ou UNIQUE, a antiga linha será apagada antes da nova linha ser inserida.*

Isso pode ser suficiente, mas claro seu banco de dados tem que está configurado corretamente e fazer uso do UNIQUE (ou do PRIMARY KEY).

---

Uma outra opção é fazer uso do [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), novamente se o seu banco de dados estiver usando `UNIQUE`.

Quando utilizar o `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, isso irá fazer um `INSERT`, porém se já existir uma linha com estes valores, será feito um `UPDATE` na linha que continha os valores informados.

Comment: on duplicate key não funciona já que estou fazendo em php com dados vindos do formulário preenchido por um usuário

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso pelo SQL mesmo dessa forma:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome = 'NOMEDOUSUARIO') 
BEGIN
   UPDATE ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ...
END
```

Tente dessa forma em php:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$nome'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($rs);

if($num > 0) {
    //Faça seu update aqui dentro
} else {
    //Faça seu insert aqui dentro
}
```

Comment: então mas é um formulário mais complexo eu criei este como base, é para um sistema web.  Queria fazer por PHP

Comment: Editei a resposta com a forma que eu faria em php. Da uma olhada aí

Comment: não roda esse comando, sequer fez insert no banco. e eu não consigo fazer funfar essa budega

Comment: Editei novamente, uma hora vc consegue kkkk